# Passing cmd line args to a class

Tags: python, pytest, playwright

im trying to pass a cmd line arg but am having difficulty. how can i pass a cmd line argument to the two_factor_verification.py file please?

test_case.py

```
@pytest.fixture
def command_line_fixtures(request):
    args = {}
    args['email'] = request.config.getoption('--email')
    args['2fa'] = request.config.getoption('--2fa')

    return args

def test_case(page: Page, command_line_fixtures) -> None:

    two_factor_page = TwoFactorVerificationPage(page)

    #two-factor
    two_factor_page.verify()
```

two_factor_verification.py

```
class TwoFactorVerificationPage():

        totp = pyotp.TOTP("[ARGUMENT HERE]")

        def __init__(self, page: Page) -> None:
            self.page = page
            self.pin_input = page.locator("[aria-label=\"Two Factor Pin\"]")
            self.verify_button = page.locator('button:has-text("Verify")')

        def verify(self) -> None:
            self.pin_input.fill(self.totp.now())
            self.verify_button.click()
```

folder structure:

```
tests
--conftest
--test_case
pages
--two_factor_verification
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does `totp` need to be a class/static variable? If not, I would make the `TwoFactorVerificationPage` constructor accept an `args` parameter:

```py
class TwoFactorVerificationPage():

        def __init__(self, page: Page, args: dict) -> None:
            self.page = page
            self.pin_input = page.locator("[aria-label=\"Two Factor Pin\"]")
            self.verify_button = page.locator('button:has-text("Verify")')
            self.totp = pyotp.TOTP("[USE args HERE]")

        def verify(self) -> None:
            self.pin_input.fill(self.totp.now())
            self.verify_button.click()
```

Otherwise, I believe you can also set `TwoFactorVerificationPage.totp = pyotp.TOTP("[USE command_line_fixtures HERE]")` from within `test_case.py`